# MS-Project 2016: Sort does not work

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

With MS-Project 2016 (version up-to-date) I have created a custom report (showing filtered tasks). I want to sort it ascending by Finish date (soonest finish on the top). But it does not work.

It sorts but it keeps the initial structure. When I sort in the normal table view, it works.

I have found other references to that but no answer that works for me
https://www.mpug.com/forums/topic/project-2013-sorting-by-date-duration-etc-not-working-in-custom-report/

It must be something very simple that I have to setup in the report. But I cannot find it.

Any help?  Many thanks